# Calling a method from external matching class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many different classes under `/lib/` folder with many actions.

Before saving an object I need to call a method from a class that matches its name with an attribute inside the object i.e. given this

```
User.gateway = "something"
```

I need to call `myfunction` from `something` class before the object is saved.

Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is quite ambiguous,is this what you need?

```
# user.rb
before_save :myfunction

protected

def myfunction
   g = self.gateway
   case g 
   when String | Symbol 
     begin
       g.classify.constantize.myfunction
     rescue NameError
       # if there is no something class
     end
   else
     # no good value
   end
end

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

[constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize) and [classify](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-classify) will do the job for you. Suppose you have:

```
class Foo
end
```

and the `"foo"` string. You can do:

```
"foo".classify.constantize.new.myfunction
```